# xcode: set custom controller class to table using storyboard

Tags: xcode, uitableview, storyboard

```
@interface HomeController : UITableViewController
```

if my custom class extends "UITableViewController", it appears and could be selected from the "Custom class" property (in the Storyboard)

In case it extends UIViewController

```
@interface HomeController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property(nonatomic,retain) UITableView *tableView;
```

it is not present in that list.

That seems to be strange for me, because

```
@interface UITableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

Note I could not change class definition, because it is a library, and I would like to use storyboard.

Many Thanks,

Comment: People, is something wrong with that question?